# Python github composite action returns name not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-actions

I am learning Github actions and I am getting error when i use composite action.
Here is my github workflow file

```
      - name: Step1
        id: action-file
        uses: ./.github/action/module
        with:
          my_name: "PythonTest"
```

And Here is action file

```
  using:  composite
  steps:
    - name: Step1
      run: print ("Hello" + ${{ inputs.my_name }})
      shell: python
```

I am getting the below error when i execute.

```
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'my_name', valid inputs are ['']
Run ./.github/action/module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/_temp/51be3e25-aa9b-4e7b-a9ff-80070e4f7754.py", line 1, in <module>
    print ("Hello" + PythonTest)
NameError: name 'PythonTest' is not defined
```

Comment: As the warning points out, try to replace "PythonTest" with 'PythonTest'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML is parsing out your `""`. As you can see in the error, `PythonTest` is passed as a symbol, not a string. You need to modify your template in order to accommodate for this:

```
  using:  composite
  steps:
    - name: Step1
      run: print ("Hello" + "${{ inputs.my_name }}")
      shell: python
```

Whatever is between the `${{}}` template will be replaced, and your test will output `"HelloPythonTest"`